# How can I get URL to a model instance in Yii2

Tags: url, yii2, polymorphic-associations

I have a polymorphic association:

```
public function getImageable()
{
    $classname = 'app\\models\\' . $this->imageable_type;
    return $this->hasOne( $classname, ['id' => 'imageable_id'] );
}
```

which can return instances of different models. I need to render a link to the `imageable` model instance in the index view. How can I do that? I need something that gives me the URL to the `view` action of the controller of `imageable_type` which is not the current controller.

```
Url:to( $controllerId . '/view', 'id' => $this->imageable_id )
```

But my problem is that how can I deternine the `controllerId` from `model`.

Comment: It's not clear what do you want to accomplish. You create links to controller's actions, not models.

Comment: Edited my question to be much clearer.

Answer (score 0):

$classname is a string.

build a

```
function getImageableName() {
   return  'app\\models\\' . $this->imageable_type;
}
```

that return the name you need

```
 Url::to($model->getImageableName())
```